# How to turn a recursive JSON-Object into a TypeScript-Class-Object?

Tags: typescript

I have an JSON-Object

```js
// The data from API call
let json_data =
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Foo",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Foobar"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Bar"
        }
    ]
```

Also an interface, that describes the JSON format:

```js
interface ICategoryTree {
    [index: number]: {
        id: number;
        name: string;
        children?: ICategoryTree;
    };
}
```

This Class is what the objects should be made of:

```js
class CategoryTree implements ICategoryTree {
    [index: number]: {
        id: number;
        name: string;
        children?: ICategoryTree;
    };

    constructor();
    constructor(data_json: ICategoryTree) {
        // todo
        // how to make an CategoryTree from an ICategoryTree-Object?
    }

    foo() {
        // fancy functionality, maybe recursive
    }
}
```

What I want to archive is, to turn the `json_data` into an object of `CategoryTree`. This does not have to be via constructor, but utilize a constructor seams to be right to me.

So I want to be able to do something like this:

```js
// does not work for now
let ct = new CategoryTree(json_data);
ct.foo();
```

Because the interface is recursive, I can't just use `Object.assign`. So this does, as far as I understand, not work:

```js
Object.assign(json_data, new CategoryTree());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would structure the types a bit differently. Instead of defining an index signature, just use an array and a class:

```
interface ICategoryTree {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  children?: ICategoryTree[];
}

class CategoryTree implements ICategoryTree {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  children?: CategoryTree[];

  constructor(values: ICategoryTree) {
      this.id = values.id;
      this.name = values.name;
      this.children = values.children !== undefined ? toCategoryTreeList(values.children) : undefined;
  }

  foo() {
  }
}

function toCategoryTreeList(values: ICategoryTree[]): CategoryTree[] {
    return values.map(tree => new CategoryTree(tree));
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
let ct = toCategoryTreeList(json_data);
ct.foo();
```

The function `toCategoryTreeList` will convert all top-level `ICategoryTree` to the class version and the constructor will then recursively call `toCategoryTreeList` to convert all it's children.

See also the implementation on the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGE6QOYHsoCeAKlBCgN4BQyywAJgFzIgCuAtgEbQDc1zcbCEwDOYKKGy8aCABbAANnVIgA-EwxYIeQiTIBtALq8AvpUoJ5cYcOSYc+YqRTA2AB3kRB4Gxvs6nyFQ09EysnDx8IAJCyKLiIJJ8sgpKEKpMdloOuhCGvEm4IHEsCGD4ABQAbnDyLBDC6pnajmQAlIF8NDRgcsIAdPTIALzI1bX1A3RSXd29fVGCw6M1df0LENMzPcD9yYrKS2OrfXupIMgAhEMjLCB0EDCgEHTIKshlTdlOADI7YFUrCanZTtJi3e6PEDPaamPgwXC4crtIIzZB8UywmC3UrAQrvXCffxkX6iAHjBpoQktXIGVoZTTNHKGDozUhgFhQc5HCZsOCucpiMjDAB8zAgAHdbAyvmQBU5Wq0TEA).